# Not able to run and build code based on ABP framework on .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, .net-core, amazon-ec2, abp

I am newbie to  ABP which is based on .net framework and.

I was going through the code of public repository of ABP framework https://github.com/abpframework/abp

my question is: What is the intention behind this code and how do we actually run it and use it as docker image if we want ?

And run it inside my cicd jenkins pipeline.

This directory contains lot of package.json, ps1, ts and json etc files.

[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5QFn.png)

[deploy structure inside this directory and framework directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcX9Z.png)

We have also lot of modules here and what's the use of this ?:

[modules structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJOEY.png)

Should I create  a new project and try to use this repo as some dependency since it  looks like some official framework code itself not the actual project.

How we are even using this for micro-service compatible by looking at the official site https://abp.io/?

How we can containerize this app and deploy it on aws ec2 linux machine ?

Will it even support on Linux machine ?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ABP is a framework as you mentioned and you can't dockerize the framework. Instead, you should create a new startup template/application via [CLI](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI) or [Get Started page](https://abp.io/get-started).

- You can use the following command to create a startup template with MVC as UI and EF Core as database provider.

```sh
dotnet tool install -g Volo.Abp.Cli
abp new Acme.BookStore -t app -u mvc --mobile none --database-provider ef -csf
```

After creating an application, you can dockerize it as you do in a .net core project.

There is a good article (and also video content) about ["Deploy a Tiered Application (based on ABP Framework) to Docker Swarm"](https://community.abp.io/posts/deploy-abp-framework-dotnet-core-tiered-app-to-docker-swarm-kcrjbjec), I suggest you to check it out.

---

> We have also lot of modules here and what's the use of this ?:

ABP Framework is a modular framework and the **Application Modules** provide pre-built application functionalities. In other words, after you've created an application based on ABP Framework, you can add pre-defined modules to it.

**For example**: ABP Framework has a module named [**Docs**](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Docs) and https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Docs uses this module.

---

> Will it even support on Linux machine ?

After you've created images for your application, you can run it in any OS you want.